# airflow subdag xcom_pull data from parent dag's task, a specific task

Tags: python, airflow

I created a dag which contains a subdag for loop through a list which is return value of a task.

## subdag function

```
    def mySubDag(parent: Text, child: Text, args, **context):
        task = context['tasl_instance']
        data = task.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1', dag_id=parent)

        for d in data:
            # do something...
```

## parent dag

```
    with DAG(...) as dag:
        task1 = PythonOperator(task_id="task1", ..., providde_context=True, dag=dag)

        task2 = SubDagOperator(subdag=mySubDag(...),..., provide_context=True, dag=dag)

        task1 >> task2
```

I dont know where to put the argument 'context' or how to put it for the subdag function to use it.

really appreciate if any one could help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

code define **xcom_pull** in **taskinstance.py**

```
def xcom_pull(
        self,
        task_ids=None,
        dag_id=None,
        key=XCOM_RETURN_KEY,
        include_prior_dates=False):


    if dag_id is None:
        dag_id = self.dag_id
    ...
```

it's pass dag_id of current dag to xom_pull

so if you want to get data from parent dag, please override dag_id argument with parent's dag_id

For your example, pass more context with op_kwargs:

```
    def set_cookies_func(config, **kwargs):
        cookies = service_get_cookies_login(config)
        kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key="SESSION", value=cookies)
    
    def get_data_func(parent_dag_name, **kwargs):
        cookies = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(
            task_ids='set_cookies_task',
            key="SESSION",
            dag_id="my_dag_id.set_cookies_task"
        )
        
    def sub_cache_load_to_gcs(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name):
        sub_dag = DAG(
            dag_id= "{}.{}".format(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
            ...
        )
        
        PythonOperator(
            task_id="get_data_func",
            python_callable=get_data_func,
            op_kwargs={"parent_dag_name": parent_dag_name},
            providde_context=True,
            dag=sub_dag
        )
    
    with DAG(
            dag_id= "my_dag_id",
            ...
    ) as dag:
        task1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id="set_cookies_task",
            python_callable=set_cookies_func,
            op_kwargs={"config": config},
            providde_context=True,
            dag=dag
        )
    
        task2 = SubDagOperator(
            task_id='branch_cache_task',
            subdag=sub_cache_load_to_gcs(dag.dag_id, 'branch_cache_task'),
            provide_context=True,
            dag=dag
        )
    
        task1 >> task2
```